# PHP: How can i read the second part of URL

Tags: php, url

How can I take out the part of the url after the view name 
Example:

The URL:

```
http://localhost/winner/container.php?fun=page&view=eims
```

Extraction

```
eims
```

Comment: why won't you use $_GET?

Comment: `$view= $_GET['view'];`

Comment: At least show us what you tried. I bet if I open google, paste your question title in it I will find at least a dozen matches.

Comment: You're missing all context. Is that currnet page URL? Is it some other URL loaded into a string? What you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

This is called a GET parameter. You can get it by using

```
<?php
    $view = $_GET['view'];
```

If this is for a URL which is not part of your website (e.g. Not your domain), but you wish to parse it. Something like this will work

```
$url = "http://example.com/index.php?foo=bar&acme=baz&view=asdf";
    $params = explode('?', $url)[1]; // This gets the text AFTER the ? Note: If using PHP 5.3 or less, this may not work. You would then need to split it into two lines with the [1] happening on $params.
    $pairs = explode('&', $params);

    foreach($pairs as $p => $pair) {
       list($keys[$p], $values[$p]) = explode('=', $pair);
          $splits[$keys[$p]] = $values[$p];
    }


echo $splits['view'];
```

Comment: What if it's not his websites URL but something from a string maybe?

Comment: Updated code again. Previous didn't work. This has been tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_GET['view']; ?>  //eims
```

Comment: @KhalidAhmed Is this the URL from your website you load the script on or do you get that URL from a string or something?

Comment: this is my site in localhost and i cannot print `$_GET['view']`

Answer (score 0):

If that's current URL, the simple and rock solid approach is to use the [filter functions](http://php.net/filter):

```
filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'view')
```

Otherwise, you can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) with `PHP_URL_QUERY` as second argument. The resulting string can be split with e.g. [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str).

Answer (score 0):

Are sure you are writing this "echo $_GET['view'];" in the container.php file?

Maybe write why do you need that "view".